# Oracle SQL group by cube with distinct ID

Tags: oracle, group-by, cube

**Example data** (complete table has more columns and millions of rows):

```
invoice_number |year            |department      |euros
-------------------------------------------------------------
1234           |2010            |1               | 200
1234           |2011            |1               | 200
1234           |2011            |2               | 200           
4567           |2010            |1               | 450
4567           |2010            |2               | 450
4567           |2010            |3               | 450
```

**My Objective:**

I want to sum the euros for every year and every department in every possible combination.

**How result should look:**

```
year             |department         |euros
--------------------------------------------
2010             |1                  |650
2010             |2                  |450
2010             |3                  |450
2010             |(null)             |650
2011             |1                  |200
2011             |2                  |200
(null)           |1                  |650
(null)           |2                  |650
(null)           |3                  |450
(null)           |(null)             |650
```

**My query:**

```
select      year
,           department
,           sum(euros)
from        table1
group by    cube    (
                    year
            ,       department
                    )
```

**Problem:**

One invoice number can occur in several categories. For example, one invoice can have items from 2010 and 2011. This is no problem when I want to show the data per year. However, when I want the total over all years the euros will be summed twice, one time for each year. I want the functionality of 'group by cube' but I want to sum only distinct invoice numbers for aggregations.

**Problem table:**

```
year             |department         |euros
--------------------------------------------
2010             |1                  |650
2010             |2                  |450
2010             |3                  |450
2010             |(null)             |1550
2011             |1                  |200
2011             |2                  |200
(null)           |1                  |850
(null)           |2                  |650
(null)           |3                  |450
(null)           |(null)             |1950
```

Is it possible to do what I want? So far my search has yielded no results. I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66fe2/2/0), I hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Removed previous "solution"]

New attempt: here is quite an ugly solution, but it seems to work, even when two invoices have the same amount. With two table accesses, you should check if performance is acceptable.

```
SQL> with table1_cubed as
  2  ( select year
  3         , department
  4         , grouping_id(year,department) gid
  5      from table1
  6     group by cube(year,department)
  7  )
  8  , join_distinct_invoices as
  9  ( select distinct x.*
 10         , r.invoice_number
 11         , r.euros
 12      from table1_cubed x
 13           inner join table1 r on (nvl(x.year,r.year) = r.year and nvl(x.department,r.department) = r.department)
 14  )
 15  select year
 16       , department
 17       , sum(euros)
 18    from join_distinct_invoices
 19   group by year
 20       , department
 21       , gid
 22   order by year
 23       , department
 24  /

      YEAR DEPARTMENT           SUM(EUROS)
---------- -------------------- ----------
      2010 1                           650
      2010 2                           450
      2010 3                           450
      2010                             650
      2011 1                           200
      2011 2                           200
      2011                             200
           1                           650
           2                           650
           3                           450
                                       650

11 rows selected.
```

Comment: Performance decreases (obviously) when I add more columns with more data. When I add all columns the group by cube generates 287.912 rows. With a smaller group I 'only' have 4.488 rows. The second one has an acceptable performance, the first one hasn't. But the solution does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select year
      ,department
      ,case when GROUPING_id(year,department) in (3) then sum(dist_euro) else sum(euros) end sums
      ,decode(GROUPING_id(year,department),0,'NO GROUP',1,'DEPARTMENT IS NULL',2,'YEAR IS NULL',3,'TOTAL OVER ALL YEARS') info
      from (
select      year
            ,           department
            ,           euros
            ,case when  row_number() over(partition by year order by year) = 1 then euros else  0 end dist_euro
from table1)
group by    cube    (
                    year
            ,       department
                    )
        order by GROUPING_id(year,department)
```

Comment: This would work if I would only want the summation for the 'year' column. However, I want this possible for every column (so in this example also for department) and in my real data set for 7 other columns. With your query the summation for (null) in department is still incorrect.